# Changing currency in Paypal SDK

Tags: javascript, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to connect to PayPal in JavaScript/React

I have the process set up but only to recognise USD.
I have tried to follow advice online which has always served me well, but struggling to get it to work with another currency like GBP

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    const addPayPalScript = async () => {
      const { data } = await Axios.get('/api/config/paypal');
      const script = document.createElement('script');
      script.type = 'text/javascript';
      script.src = "https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id='myclientid'&currency=GBP";
      
      script.async = true;
      script.onload = () => {
        setSdkReady(true);
      };
      document.body.appendChild(script);
    };
```

Then when I'm at the button

```
<PayPalButton 
  amount={order.totalPrice}
  onSuccess={successPaymentHandler}
></PayPalButton>
```

I also have currency as a field in order.currency.

The errors go from
Unexpected currency: USD passed to order.create. Please ensure you are passing /sdk/js?currency=USD in the paypal script tag.
to
Unexpected currency: GBP passed to order.create. Please ensure you are passing /sdk/js?currency=GBP in the paypal script tag.

Comment: How are you formatting `client-id='myclientid'` ? There should be no quotation marks

Comment: No, I don't have any quotation marks around that. I put them their to try make it clearer but obviously not haha, so the code works if I am OK with the amount being in usd, but I need it in gbp.

Comment: Well if you are passing currency=GBP then it should work for creating an order with GBP, but you haven't shown us the latter

Comment: Do you know if i need to define the {order.totalPrice} to be GDP somewhere?

Comment: When you create the payment it needs to be in GBP. Who knows what's going on behind that <PayPalButton> abstraction, you're obviously using something like a react object but we can't advise on what we can't see

Comment: Maybe you're using this thing: https://github.com/Luehang/react-paypal-button-v2#large_blue_diamond-props

Comment: I really appreciate your help. With regards to your link, I thought {clientId: "sb", currency: "USD"} was the equivalent to "https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id='myclientid'&currency=GBP", so i'm already specifying currency? So to me i feel like i need to define the order.total to be GBP but i am not sure how, I have googled currency formatters: function formatToCurrency(amount){
    return (amount).toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '£&,'); 
} Is something like this going to help do you know? or is this just for displaying numbers?

Comment: You are specifying the currency on the SDK line, but currency in the createOrder should match.  If you are using that thing I linked to, it has a parameter for the <PayPalButton>

Comment: OMG! I was just coming back, i thought i had tried this, i must have had a typo or something when i originally tried, i have just managed to do it. Thank you so much for your patience :) That is so annoying haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update: the official [react-paypal-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@paypal/react-paypal-js) module should be used instead

When using [the non-official] https://github.com/Luehang/react-paypal-button-v2#large_blue_diamond-props

There is a parameter for "Currency", e.g.

```
<PayPalButton 
    amount={order.totalPrice}
    currency="GBP"
    onSuccess={successPaymentHandler}
></PayPalButton>
```

This is the currency when creating the order, which (if specified in the code this is abstracting), needs to match the currency on the SDK load line.

Comment: How do I change the currency in Paypal dynamically without passing currency param at the script tag? It's NOT a React App.

is there any way to do that or just I have to redownload the whole PayPal script? for that,

Wired PayPal SDK!!

Comment: You can't. It's a required parameter when loading the script, to evaluate which buttons to show for that currency.  If you want to reload the script dynamically use `paypal-js` from npm or for vanilla JS see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68371011/toggle-between-paypal-order-and-paypal-subscription

Comment: What kinda system paypal designed! this looks PayPal is a poor guy!  I'm trying to integrate paypal-js it still does throwing errors :( 

when clicking pay button, it rejecting and in the console says `click_initiate_payment_reject` with other logs.

Comment: the SO link you provided is working cool. but there is a recycling issue. when currency changes I can re-initiate it but what about the ones had already? it doesn't delete the previous one.

Comment: The code adds the script to where it takes precedence. If you want to remove the other script tags you can write code for that.

Comment: In the same package just initialise your PayPalScriptProvider currency with the currency you want to use.
const initialOptions = {
    "client-id": "test",
    currency: "USD",
};

export default function App() {
    return (
        <PayPalScriptProvider options={initialOptions}>
            <PayPalButtons />
        </PayPalScriptProvider>
    );
}